# Marionette.js CompositeView won't render Children

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Here is my CompositeView:

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!fonts/products/template.html",
'fonts/products/item-view', 'fonts/products/collection', 'fonts/products/model'],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML, ProductItemView, ProductsCollection, ProductsModel) {
    'use strict';

    var ProductsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName: "div",

        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        childView: ProductItemView,

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new ProductsCollection({
                model: ProductsModel
            });
        },

        onRender: function() {
            this.collection.fetch();
        }
    });

    return ProductsView;
});
```

And here is my ItemView:

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!fonts/products/item-view.html"],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML) {
    'use strict';

    var ProductItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'div',

        template: _.template(templateHTML)
    });

    return ProductItemView;

});
```

Even though the CompositeView is rendered, the children won't render even after the collection is fetched

Comment: Have you tried rendering the composite view with a filled collection?

Comment: I figured out my problem, forgot to post. The Content-type was application/x-json-stream and was causing errors with Backbone trying to retrieve the data correctly

Comment: Architecture note: You should probably delegate fetching responsibilities to controller.  Also, I'm not a big fan of instantiating collections and models inside views.